# How to assign a dedicated certificate to a sub-directory for proxy pass in Apache?

Tags: apache

I want to ProxyPass “/” and /sub-dir” to different target.

OK – putting two ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse command in a  block works.

But I need a different* SSLCertificateFile, SSLCertificateChainFile, SSLCertificateKeyFile, SSLVerifyClient and SSLCACertificateFile for each sub-directory.

Using  SSLCertificateFile in a  block is not allowed and when using two  blocks (with ProxyPass  sub-directory in the first one) “/” is not proxy passed (getting “certificate signed by unknown authority" error – when disabling the first   block it works).

(* monitoring* is LetsEncrypt for a website,  ca_user.crt=self signed is for general client authentication to the website,  server_monitoring* and corresponding  ca_monitoring.crt are for IOT devices = self signed)

```
<VirtualHost 0.0.0.0:443>
  ServerName my-domain
  ServerAlias www.my-domain
  ProxyPass  http://sub-dir http://target1:3000 retry=5 keepalive=on Timeout=3600
  ProxyPassReverse  http://sub-dir target1:3000
  ProxyPass  http://sub-dir2 http://target2:3000 retry=5 keepalive=on Timeout=3600
  ProxyPassReverse  http://sub-dir2 target2:3000
  SSLCertificateFile conf/monitoring.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile conf/monitoring.key
  SSLVerifyClient on
  SSLCACertificateFile conf/ca_user.crt
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 0.0.0.0:443>
  ServerName my-domain
  ProxyPass / http://pushprox:8081/ retry=5
  ProxyPassReverse / http://pushprox:8081/
  SSLCertificateFile conf/server_monitoring.crt
  SSLCertificateChainFile conf/ca_monitoring.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile conf/server_monitoring.key
  SSLVerifyClient on
  SSLCACertificateFile conf/ca_monitoring.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: By the way - putting the <VirtualHost> block with ProxyPass / at the top and adding 
    ProxyPass sub-dir !
    ProxyPassReverse sub-dir !
to it did not help.

Comment: Oh - isn't it correct that there can be only one certificate per subdomain because in the "Hello Message" of TLS there is (SNI) is only the subdomain present and nothing else like the called sub-directory?

Answer (score 1):

Because only the subdomain (SNI) and not he full URL is transmitted before the TLS handshake the server cannot decide which CA to use. Thus, it is impossible to use a dedicated CA per sub-dir.
With ALPN it would be possible - but the question was just about URL.